# Dovecot Sieve filters not working

Tags: php, postfix-mta, roundcube, sieve-language

I'm having an issue where dovecot-sieve is not working for me from within Roundcube. In the Roundcube web interface the filters tab is there as well as the vacation tab. I can edit, save, enable, and disable filters just fine, but despite the vacation filter being enabled and setup for the correct date(s), no messages are sent. I can send from within the interface just fine when creating HTML messages from within Roundcube, the issue just seems to be sieve kicking off vacation messages. To the best of my knowledge (not great with this kinda thing), I should have everything set up correctly. Please see my configs below, I've only included the appropriate pieces of code:

/etc/dovecot/conf.d/90-sieve.conf:

```
plugin {
 sieve = ~/.dovecot.sieve
 sieve = ~/.dovecot.sieve
 sieve_global_dir = /var/lib/dovecot/sieve/
 sieve_before          = /etc/dovecot/common.sieve
 sieve_extenesions = +vacation
}
```

/etc/dovecot/conf.d/20-managesieve.conf:

```
protocols = $protocols sieve

service managesieve-login {
 inet_listener sieve {
    port = 4190
  }
```

/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf:

```
protocols = imap pop3 lmtp sieve imaps
```

/var/www/website.com/plugins/managesieve/config.inc.php:

```
$config['managesieve_port'] = 4190;
$config['managesieve_host'] = 'localhost';
$config['managesieve_auth_type'] = null;
$config['managesieve_auth_cid'] = null;
$config['managesieve_auth_pw'] = null;
$config['managesieve_usetls'] = false;
$config['managesieve_default'] = '/etc/dovecot/sieve/global';
$config['managesieve_script_name'] = 'managesieve';
$config['managesieve_replace_delimiter'] = '';
$config['managesieve_disabled_extensions'] = array();
$config['managesieve_debug'] = true;
$config['managesieve_kolab_master'] = false;
$config['managesieve_filename_extension'] = '.sieve';
$config['managesieve_filename_exceptions'] = array();
$config['managesieve_domains'] = array();
$config['managesieve_vacation'] = 1;
$config['managesieve_notify_methods'] = array('mailto');
```

/var/www/website.com/config/config.inc.php:

```
$config['plugins'] = array('managesieve','jqueryui');
$config['smtp_server'] = 'localhost';
$config['default_host'] = 'localhost';
$config['force_https'] = true;
```

Also, I can see it running on port 4190 as well:

```
#netstat -tunlp | grep :4190 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4190            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11214/dovecot        
tcp6       0      0 :::4190                 :::*                    LISTEN      11214/dovecot
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue.  I had configured mail_plugins for LDA but was actually using LMTP!  Once I configured mail_plugins = $mail_plugins sieve for LMTP the vacation message kicked in.

Answer (score 0):

Dovecot has must have LDA or LMTP enabled. See https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/sieve/troubleshooting/. LMTP is better option.

Also enable logging under `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-logging.conf`, by setting `mail_debug = yes`. Then `tail -f /var/log/syslog` to follow what exactly is happening.

Comment: @LaserGuidedCake: while your edit concerning the URL `https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/sieve/troubleshooting` is correct. Please prefer to comment issues like this. Edits shouldn't contain any significant content changes.